# When using openssl to encrypt a file, how would I create a key made up of specific letters?

Tags: encryption, openssl, aes, file-encryption

I want to create a 128bit AES key made up of specific letters. I think I would need to use something like

openssl genrsa -aes128 -out privkey.pem

or

openssl genrsa -out privkey.pem

but I'm not sure how to make an AES with a 128bit key made up of specific letters that I choose. Am I thinking of this in the wrong way?

Edit: I wonder if doing something like 
openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -k secret -P -md sha1
 would work

Comment: *"Am I thinking of this in the wrong way?"* - totally. The problem you describe makes no sense from the technical perspective. Apart from that the key is binary, i.e. there is no notion of a "character" at all in this context only. Even if it would it makes no sense to restrict the key this way. You could of course represent any binary data as printable characters with an appropriate encoding like base64 or hex, but that's just a representation and does not change the actual key.

Comment: The problem is to use AES with a 128 bit key which is made up of two letters repeated 8 times. Then using that AES to encrypt a file. I'm not sure how I can make an AES key that is made up of two characters repeated 8 times. It just doesnt make sense to me because AES makes a random one.

Comment: Please know that you should not use OpenSSL as a general-purpose encryption utility. It is insecure for those purposes and only exists to allow you to test the underlying OpenSSL library functionality.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I think it might make sense, depending on what he was doing - for instance, 4chan has a "tripcode" option that allows the user to enter a password after their username which is then encrypted and displayed after their username as a way of authenticating their identity on an otherwise-anonymous forum, and deliberately engineering a particular tripcode could be useful if you want to encode a particular message into it.

Comment: *"The problem is to use AES with a 128 bit key which is made up of two letters repeated 8 times. "* - again, the key is binary. There is no such thing as "letters" in the key. But if you want to use a specific key you've created you can just use the `-K` option (uppercase `K`, this is different from `-k password` you are using) to make `openssl enc` use exactly this key. See [the documentation](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Enc) for the details.

Comment: I'm doing a class assignment and it says using command-line open ssl, encrypt a copy of the file. Use AES with a 128bit key which is made up two letters repeating. The way the professor gave to  generate the private and public pair is  $  openssl genrsa   -out   private.pem  1024 but that doesnt make sense as I dont know where I need to put the made up of part.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich using -k sounds like what i need to do. I have no idea why that isn't mentioned anywhere in the powerpoint slides i was given or anywhere in class and when i was searching for information online for the past 30 minutes nothing about using -k to use your own came up at all but im happy for it thank you.

Comment: @SelfHatingLoser Tripcodes are not good examples, because they make use of an ancient DES-based hash (after conversion to SJIS). There are reasons why it's so easy to brute force trips.

Comment: I know it's not a good example, but I still am required to do it.

Comment: also using -k didn't work but i think it didnt work because i was trying to use it doing openssl   rsautl  -encrypt   when i need to be doing openssl enc. So im gonna try doing openssl enc

Comment: Yeah I was wondering why you were using `genrsa`...

Comment: The only example the professor gave used genrsa so I thought it was what I was supposed to be using which probably added to my confusion. I got it to work now so thanks all! :)